# How do I switch between Unity and Budgie desktop environments in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: unity, lightdm, desktop-environments, budgie

I did the following to get the budgie-remix on my Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:budgie-remix/ppa
sudo apt install budgie-desktop-environment budgie-desktop budgie-welcome
```

then I restarted the computer.

However, contrary to my assumptions, I did not get any option to choose between budgie and unity at the logon screen, which was a new one (budgie style, but I like lightdm). After login, unity opened up, but the sidebar of budgie has **also** launched. I want to separate the components of unity and budgie out.

Comment: were you able to solve that? I am having the same issue and I can't seem to recover my setup after a purge even

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry for having forgotten to update the status. Yes, I solved it. Check the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The catch was centered around the packages that came with budgie (because of which, I had plank overlapping with the unity panel,etc.) and the **greeter** (to fix the crappy login/lockscreens which prevented switch between budgie and unity).

I searched around a proper way to install budgie-remix on ubuntu xenial and found that just

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:budgie-remix/ppa  
sudo apt install budgie-desktop budgie-welcome
```

was enough. Apparently installing `budgie-desktop-environment` was bringing in so many additional packages bundled with that desktop environment (which are general utlities generally installed when an operating system is installed) which were unnecessary and in fact overlapping over similar packages provided by Ubuntu. So I purged and reinstalled using above commands.

After installing again, I had to change the default greeter to the default one used by Ubuntu, the `unity-greeter`. Budgie uses its version of the `gtk-greeter` which wouldn't allow a switch between the two desktop environments.

I guess we can use `unity-greeter` only if running `lightdm`  as the display manager. Luckily, budgie uses `lightdm`, so it was just a matter of changing the greeter session to `unity-greeter`.

I just had to edit the `greeter-session` option in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`, then change the line

```
greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter //(or whatever was after the '=', I don't remember clearly)
```

back to

```
greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

Comment: `lightdm-gtk-greeter` does allow switching DEs, but, IIRC, the option is somewhere in the top panel (or not, depending on the theme).

Comment: No, there was no option to switch at all. The greeter was an edited version, by budgie.